# JQuery Validate, How to Customize Error Message?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to customize the error messages shown by Jquery Validate,
It is currently showing `"Email is already taken"`, but what I want is for example the user entered `user@yahoo.com,` and it's already taken, I want to see `"user@yahoo.com" is already taken`. My field ID is user_email, `I tried using $('#user_email).val()` in the example but it's not showing. I have the fallowing code.
Thanks in advance!

```
remote: {
  url: user_email_availability_url,
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  complete: function() {
  }
}

messages: {
  "user[email]": {
  remote:  $('#user_email').val() + "is already taken",
  email: 'Invalid email address'
},
```

Comment: what *is* showing, in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you should try making that message a function (I believe that's possible):

```
remote: function(value) {
 return value + " is already taken"
 }
```

Comment: Very helpful,  is there a way to retrieve responseText from the remote method to be displayed in message?

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin file you can find line(about 230) where all error messages are setuped.

I hope it will be helpfull